# Redirecting ip to domain name

Tags: linux, apache, dns, url-masking, domain-masking

I am working on a small project,
I changed http://localhost to http://myowndomain.com and it's working good.
I was curious and gave domain name to facebook.com  . But it will redirect to original Facebook website.

I got an idea, and used apache rule

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12\.34\.56\.789$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Here, in the place of domainname if I use Facebook it will again redirect to original site.

Is there any way to so that I can bind my offline Facebook page (index.html) with my static ip address and I someone enters my ip, they get facebook.com in the domain name.

Comment: Did you edit /etc/hosts? And, are you using windows or linux?

Comment: Yes, I am using linux and I edited /etc/hosts also

Comment: Maybe restart PC once... And clear cache in your browser

Comment: Ok,  I am on it.

Comment: Let me know if it works after...

Comment: Yes, it's working good ,after I clear all browser datas. I used internal ip. If I use static ip and if I do same thing and send it to others, will it work.

Comment: Nice. That's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Sppofing dns replies is an overkill and modified hosts files on every pc is tedious.
Not knowing your network doesn't help either but if I were you, to achieve what you want, I would use bind and rpz (https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/) or dnsmaquerade (easier solution).

About your original problem, what you should do is:

- make sure myowndomain.com resolves to the ip of the server where pages are located (resoluton is done by the DNS server the client is using)
- if you need a rewrite rule to redirect traffic, first you need 2 virtual hosts: one handling request for the domain you want to use and a default one catching every other requests. The default one is the only one where you should put a rewrite rule to redirect everything to your main website.
  The rule you need in the default vhost is something like this:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond (.*) http://domainname.com$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

Please remember "domainname.com" and "www.domainname.com" are different domains: both need to be resolved with an ip address (which can be the same) so if you want to use both domains, the virtualhost you have to setup must be configured to handle requests for for domains and it should look like this:

```
ServerName domainname.com
ServerAlias www.domainname.com
#ServerAlias *.domainname.com
```